# Parsing a XML String to an array String

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm working on java project. When I send a request to Marklogic server it response by a `ResultSequence`

```
ResultSequence object.
```

and when I print this results

```
rs.asString
```

I get.

```
<name>hadoop</name>
<name>spark</name>
<name>hive</name>
```

my aim is to have a `arrayString` as

```
 Result[]=(hadoop,spark,hive)
```

how can i parse this XML string to a `ArrayString`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the only tag you are getting is `<name>` then you can go for a find-replace solution. you can use `regex` to remove tag :

```
String string = "<name>Hadoop</name>";
string.replaceAll("<name>(.*)</name>", "$1")
```

And then put all strings in an array.

But if there are more tags and you also want to work on them you should better use some XML Parser

> For example: if the content is in a xml file then

```
File names = new File("name.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(names);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");

String[] namesArray = new String[nodes.getLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Node node = nodes.item(i);
  namesArray[i]=node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Now `namesArray` will have node values

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [xstream](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/08/18/xstream.html) for XML (de)serialization. It is way simpler than using Java's built-in XML APIs. And then you just follow their example.